# "yellow useless part" or "useless yellow part"?

Tags: adjectives, word-order, adjective-phrases, adjective-order

This may be a simple question but it has me confused. Is it "yellow useless part" or "useless yellow part" in the sentence below?

> He threw the yellow useless part of cigarette.

By *useless yellow part*, I mean the part that remains after you are done smoking a cigarette i.e, cigarette butt.

Comment: Is the useless part includes several color bands among which yellow?

Comment: As a learner: I see, I am saying if you say yellow useless part, in general, it may mean there are other parts and he did something only to the yellow part. However, here the context is very clear. As I said, I would say "useless yellow part", but I am not a native guy. Let's wait for them 0-:)

Comment: It should be, "He threw **away** the ***useless, yellow*** part of **the** cigarette."

Comment: And the “away” can be omitted with a few more words of detail, such as: “He threw the useless, yellow part of the cigarette **out the window**.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the rules of adjective order at [Ginger](http://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/adjectives/order-of-adjectives/), quality (useless) comes before color (yellow), but how seriously this is supposed to be taken, I can only guess!